# How to correctly select ccTLD domain for same speaking native language countries?

Tags: seo, domains, local-seo, cctld

We know that South America's native-speaking language Portuguese (Brazil) and Spanish (Spain, Argentina, Colombia, Chile, Peru, Uruguay, etc.). My keyword targeting audience to South American users.

I want to take a second-level domain **example.com.es** (Spain) that will run with a micro-niche blog website and will need to target both country + language.

Now, Can I rank South American's Spanish language country with **example.com.es**?

Can I get any SEO facilities for Spanish 2 letter language code - **es**

and for Portuguese language **example.com.es/pt**

that's a good or bad strategy?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use country code domains for languages purposes and get SEO rankings outside the country of the domain.   Google only shows `example.com.es` URLs in Spain.   Those URLs won't show up in Spanish speaking South American countries.

The only way to get a domain to rank on Google in multiple countries is to use  a [generic top-level domain](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites):

> Generic Top Level Domains (gTLDs): Unless a top level domain is registered as a country code top level domain (ccTLD) with ICANN, Google will treat any TLD that resolves through the IANA DNS root zone as a gTLD. Examples:
>
> - .com
> - .org
> - .edu
> - .gov
> - and many more...
>
> Generic regional top-level domains: Although these domains are associated with a geographical region, they are generally treated as generic top-level domains (much like .com or .org):
>
> - .eu
> - .asia
>
> Generic Country Code Top Level Domains (ccTLDs): Google treats some ccTLDs (such as .tv, .me, etc.) as gTLDs, as we've found that users and website owners frequently see these more generic than country-targeted. Here is a list of those ccTLDs (this list may change).
>
> - .ad
> - .as
> - .bz
> - .cc
> - .cd
> - .co
> - .dj
> - .fm
> - .io
> - .la
> - .me
> - .ms
> - .nu
> - .sc
> - .sr
> - .su
> - .tv
> - .tk
> - .ws

Answer (score -1):

There are no ccTLD content restrictions. You can put, for example, English content inside an `.es` (Spain) ccTLD.

In my opinion, using a country to target a specific language audience is an error, because the language is above the countries.

Try to use a generic TLD like, `com`, `net`, `org` or the new ones as `online`, `site`, etc.